# makefile convert $(SOURCES) to $(OBJECTS)

Tags: path, makefile

i have a list of paths to sources in subfolders of /source in $(SOURCES). Paths are like this:

```
  $(SOURCES)=
    source/main.cpp
    source/subfolder/code.cpp
    ....
```

how can i convert all of 'em in this format?

```
  $(OBJECTS)=
    obj/main.o
    obj/code.o
    ....
```

or at least how to automatically create all the missing folders in obj/ and change "source" to "obj" in paths?

Comment: read a makefile tutorial :)

Comment: `$(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))`